# What is the largest/least value of the function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, optimization

What is the largest/least value of the function $f=x^2ye^{-x^2-2y^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

We have that $f'_x=y\left(2e^{-x^2-2y^2}x-2e^{-x^2-2y^2}x^3\right)$ and $f'_y=x^2\left(e^{-x^2-2y^2}-4e^{-x^2-2y^2}y^2\right)$. If $x=0$ then $f'_x=f'_y=0$ so $(0,y)$, where $y\in \mathbb{R}^2$ are stationary points.

Further $1-4y^2=0\iff y=+-1/\sqrt{2}$ and $2x-2x^3=0\iff2x(1-x^2)\iff x=0, x=+-1$ so $+-(1,1/\sqrt{2})$ are also stationary points.

The values for the stationary points are $f(0,y)=0$, $f(+-1,1/\sqrt{2})=\frac{e^{-2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $f(+-1,-1/\sqrt{2})=-\frac{e^{-2}}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Now how do I prove that $e^{-2}/\sqrt{2}$ is the largest value and $-e^{-2}/\sqrt{2}$  is the smallest? Would be nice with a blueprint that I can use for any function but I guess it doesn't exist.

**Edit:** Not looking for solutions that splits up the $f$ to $x^2e^{-x^2}ye^{-2y^2}$.

I wrote an answer and hopefully someone can check that it is right.

Comment: Indeed, this is a subtle matter: With more than one variable, you can have a local minimum but *no* global minimum. So, although you can use the second derivative test to establish that you have a local maximum/minimum, you really need to make some global arguments. In this case, the nature of the exponential function  tells you that $f(x,y)\to 0$ as $\|(x,y)\|\to\infty$.

Comment: How can I use this information to show the least and largest values? Calculus books I have seen so far only cover this when the domain is bounded so I'm lost.

Comment: To be rigorous, you need to apply the extreme value theorem on a compact (closed and bounded) set and estimate the function to show that it's larger/smaller outside that compact set. In your case, you need to use the fact that exponentials grow faster than polynomials to do the estimate outside a ball of radius $2$ or $10$ ...

Comment: The form of $f$ conveniently allows you to separate the variables, leaving you with two similar univariate problems to solve.

Comment: Ok, so I have a ball(circle)$ x^2+y^2<r^2$ where r is large enough so that the ball contains the points $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=e^{-2}/\sqrt{2}$. Now I need to do two things: 1 Check the boundary points so I can use the extreme value theorem, 2 show that the function is less when outside the ball. For 1 should I substitute $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$ with $0\leq\theta<2\pi$ ? Also how do I check that the function is less outside of the circle? Since $f(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $||(x,y)||\rightarrow \infty$ if i increase the boundary ,i.e. r then the value given by boundary shouapproach 0.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley you mean $x^2ye^{-x^2-2y^2}=x^2e^{-x^2}ye^{-2y^2}$. I've seen this but it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: A *Star Wars* quote comes to mind. :)

Comment: Per, can you follow the line of thinking from Ted Shifrin's comments? That is a standard way of dealing with problems like this. Find a large disk where you can give estimates proving that outside that disk the values of the function are close to zero. Then in that disk you can use the general result saying that maximum and minimum are both achieved. Then replace with a bigger disk to deduce that you can ignore the boundary also. The function is differentiable everywhere, so it follows that the extrema can only be achieved at *a critical point* (that you call stationary points).

Comment: Honestly I don't understand that idea well. But I already have good explanations(I'm guessing) so if I can see an example then it would be easier to understand. Also even if understood the idea I don't think I would be able to rigorously prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$ and $h(y)=ye^{-2y^2}.$ Then $g[\Bbb R]=[0,e^{-1}]$ and $h[\Bbb R]=[-2^{-1/2}e^{-1},2^{-1/2}e^{-1}]$. Therefore $f[\Bbb R^2]=\{uv:u\in g[\Bbb R]\land v\in h[\Bbb R]\}=[-2^{-1/2}e^{-2},2^{-1/2}e^{-2}].$

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear but I'm not looking for a solution like this. I'm looking for the more general solution where using the fact that $f(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $|(x,y)|\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make a circle(ball) that contains the critical points. By the extreme value theorem there will be a greatest and least value within that circle. If we can show that the boundary points' f-value approaches 0 as the radius get larger then we have shown that for an arbitrary large circle that contains the critical points they will give greatest and least value. In our case the max and min value are $\frac {e^{-2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and  $\frac {e^{-2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ respectively.

Let $\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta \\ y=r\sin\theta \end{cases}$ where $0 \leq\theta\leq 2\pi$. We need to show that $\lim _{r\rightarrow\infty}=r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta e^{-r^2\cos^2\theta-2r^2\sin^2\theta}=0$.

Since $-r^2\cos^2\theta -2r^2\sin^2\theta=-r^2(\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta)=-r^2(1+sin^2\theta)\leq -r^2\iff e^{-r^2(1+\sin^2\theta)}\leq e^{-r^2}$ we have that $r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta e^{-r^2\cos^2\theta-2r^2\sin^2\theta}\leq r^3e^{-r^2}\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$. So we have shown that for large enough r, radius of the circle, the boundary points will have f-values close to 0 and as $r$ gets larger the boundary points of the f-values will get closer to 0. Since we can choose an arbitrarily large $r$ it means that $\frac {e^{-2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and  $\frac {e^{-2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ are the largest and least value respectively in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The function to be optimized on $\Bbb R^2$ is $f(x,y)=x^2ye^{-x^2-2y^2}$. The system of equations for the critical points $f_x=f_y=0$ is equivalent to the system $2xy(1-x^2)=0$ and $x^2(1-4y^2)=0.$ The solution of the system is $S=\{(0,y)|y\in\Bbb R\}\cup\{A(1,\frac12),B(-1,\frac12), C(1,-\frac12), D(-1,-\frac12)\}$. The values at these critical points: $f(0,y)=0$, $f(A)=f(B)=\frac12e^{-\frac32}$ and $f(C)=f(D)=-\frac12e^{-\frac32}.$ Since, the domain of the function is open and $\lim_{x^2+y^2\rightarrow\infty}f(x,y)=0$ we decide: Global max. of $f(x,y)$ is $\frac12e^{-\frac32}$ at $A,B$ and Global min. of $f(x,y)$ is $-\frac12e^{-\frac32}$ at $C,D.$

[Note](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Optimize%20f%28x%2Cy%29%3Dx%5E2ye%5E%28-x%5E2-2y%5E2%29): WA says no global max and min. Why?